# change color of all buttons on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

what's happening:

The Color of only the first button gets changed. And it gets changed on clicking any other button.

what should happen:

The Color of the button should get changed on clicking that particular button.

What mistake am I making, can't figure out.

```js
/*search-box*/

$('#click').click(function()
{   
    $("#search-box").toggle();     
});


/*seat-color*/
 var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFC0CB"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "#800080"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

```css
 #search-box{
 height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background:red;
    display: none;
    font-size: xx-large;

 }
 
    #button{
 height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    background:pink; 
 }
```

```html
<! doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="custom_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>  

</head>  
  
<body>


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id="click" value="Show/Hide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button>
 
    <div id="search-box">
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink"onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>
  
 
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
     
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<!--Custome Jquery-->
<script src="custom_js/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have mistakes in html elements : ` style="margin:10px;" "color:pink"` double center quotes are no expected. `id` tag is designed to be unique, change to `class`tag, maybe add uniques `name` or `id` in order to use the submit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JQuery :

```
<html>
    <title>Demo</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id="click" value="Show/Hide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Search</button>

       <div id="search-box">
    <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button" style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink"onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button"  style="margin:10px;" "color:pink" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010');"/></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set firstime color if needed
    toogleColor();     

    $('#click').click(function() { toogleColor(); });
    function toogleColor() {
        $('.button').each(function(el) { 
            console.log('coucou');
            this.style.backgroundColor = this.style.backgroundColor !== "blue"
                ? "blue"
                : "red";
        });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used class with button and tried above Jquery but it is not working

Comment: Works perfectly, I put all code here [jssfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeanLucB/a1v4pzc5/1/) and in my updated post.

Comment: Although this works fine but this is not my query :)  :(
What should happen:
The Color of the button should get changed on clicking that particular button not the "btn btn-default btn-success".This button is just meant for opening up search div. Buttons inside  this div, when clicked individually should change their respective color

Comment: I update the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeanLucB/a1v4pzc5/3/). Tell me if it right ?

Comment: Welcome, please +1 answer too :)